# JSON from twitter API contains \u2019

Tags: php, mysql, json, twitter

This is part of my JSON file I obtain through the twitter API:

> "text":"Scientists discover new method for studying molecules: Queen\u2019s researchers have discovered the method for studyi... http://bit.ly/chbweE"

I am using PHP for my project.

After using the json_decode function, \u2019 is converted into â€™, which basically is really annoying.

I tried using `$raw_json = preg_replace("u2019","'",$raw_json)`, but then the `json_decode` function returns NULL.

Is there any other way I can convert the \u2019 into '  ?

Thanks

---

Edit:

This is how I am obtaining the JSON:

```
// create curl resource
    $ch = curl_init();

    // set url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from%3Agizmodo&rpp=10");

    //return the transfer as a string
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // $output contains the output string
    $raw_json = curl_exec($ch);

    // close curl resource to free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: please provide the method/function that describe how you get the contents via twitter API, in nutshell, is a encoding problem, lots of reason can introduce garbled text, such as page encoding

Comment: I am using the Search API... so http://search.twitter.com/search.json

Comment: lots of method to use the twitter, curl, fopen, socket... can it be more specific ? or put in the particular code for content grabbing

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that I am executing the search using the cURL functions in php

Comment: it is nothing wrong, please change your page encoding to UTF-8, and see does it still causing problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably a problem with the charset you're using in your output. If you're outputing to an HTML page, try adding the following meta tag to your `<head>` section:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: Thanks, you're a hero. You've got no idea how important that line of code was for my site. If you want to check it out, here is the link: [http://bloging.net16.net/](http://bloging.net16.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the regex delimiters `/.../` in `preg_replace`. Try:

```
$raw_json = preg_replace("/u2019/","'",$raw_json);
```

Also, to be even safer, I'd only replace those instances that are actually escape characters:

```
$raw_json = preg_replace("/\\\\u2019/","\\'",$raw_json);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you'd use `preg_replace` in this particular instance instead of `str_replace`?

Comment: @beanland: Not really, I just used what the OP posted in the question, but `str_replace` would be just fine.