# json_decode \u2019

Tags: php, html, encoding, json

I have a JSON file I am reading in through PHP and echoing out to an HTML file. Within the JSON file there is this string:  `Lisa\u2019s husband`

That [`\u2019`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm) is a "right single quotation mark" and should be output as such; instead, I get this:  `â€™`

I've tried [specifying a UTF-8 encoding on my HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4212191/390977), but it doesn't fix the problem--it just makes it different.

**Without Specifying Encoding**

`â€™`

**Specifying a UTF-8 Encoding in the HTML File**

`â��`

**Headers Sent**

```
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:3918
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Mon, 19 Mar 2012 21:21:04 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=500
MS-Author-Via:DAV
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.7l PHP/5.2.15
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.2.15
```

What do I need to do to get my apostrophe to look the right way? I do not want to replace these values with `'`

**Edit**

Specifying `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` changed my headers but did not fix the issue.

Comment: Have you tried the named entity? `&rsquo;`

Comment: According to [this page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm), `\u2019` is `C/C++/Java source code`.  Browsers only interpret HTML code which is `&#x2019;` or `&rsquo;`.

Comment: @PetrMarek I could, but then I would need to do a replace on all possible codes like this with their associated entity code.

Comment: You should probably look at the [_other_ answer on that page](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4212191/390977) for more information about how to _convert_ your JSON characters into HTML.

Comment: @Sparky672 What I am doing is taking a plaintext file, converting it to JSON, and then presenting aspects of it in a web page, all through PHP.  The plaintext file has a `’`.  It is somewhere in the json_encode() (I believe) where the apostrophe is transformed into `\u2019`.  Is it possible to change the output with one of the json_encode options?

Comment: @Sparky672 Also, more relevantly, the `\uHHHH` escapement syntax is also built-in into JavaScript string literals. (Which means that if that JSON sting were retrieved via Ajax and parsed with JavaScript, it would work...)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, isn't that what [the other answer on that question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4212191/390977) is about?

Comment: Maybe I'm just too stubborn, but I would think that if json_encode turns `’` into `\u2019`, json_decode should turn `\u2019` into `’`. If that's not the case, I can go ahead and just do a global string replacement, but it seems odd to me that it's not doing that.

Comment: Well, it's trying to, but PHP and charsets...

Comment: Works fine for me: http://3v4l.org/4tcqD **You** are handling encodings incorrectly at some point, `json_decode` is fine. Perhaps you have some random `utf8_encode` somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

\u2019 is unicode or UTF-16. UTF-8 creates 8-bit character combinations like \x##\x##. You need to convert the string from unicode to utf-8 before parsing it with php json_decode. Finally after decoding it you have to convert the values to their htmlentities by directly calling the function (ie. if the field you want to decode is cars in races object.

```
<?php

// Convert from unicode to utf-8

// json_decode

echo htmlentities(races.cars[1])

?>
```